# How can I detect when a game is over from my Activity?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making a game with Libgdx. In my activity class there is the following code. I want to be able to detect when it is gameover from the android activity so that I can close the activity and start a new one.

How can I communicate with the activity the game?

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

        game = new MainGame();

        initialize(game, cfg);
    }
```

Comment: `(Player Lives == 0 && Player Health == 0) || (Final Big Boss Health == 0 && Level == Last One)`?

Comment: @BobMalooga how can I detect this in the android activity not the game

Comment: When the onDestroy method is fired, maybe?

Comment: you can send a callback to you MainGame class. Then, call that callback after a gameover.